# Build C# application and send results to SonarQube dashboard

Tags: c#, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

I'm working on a POC.I need to send the build results to SonarQube dashboard. I managed to get it worked in local.

I followed SonarScanner for .NET page in the SonarQube documentation.

```
SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"project-key" /d:sonar.login="myAuthenticationToken" 
MSBuild.exe <path to solution.sln> /t:Rebuild
SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end /d:sonar.login="myAuthenticationToken"
```

then I added **/d:sonar.host.url** and changed project-key and Authentication token ran it for production server and its running without any errors but the results on the dashboard is empty. Do i need to add any specific parameters when building for production server?

When I build it for localhost, its generating the output-cs folder but for production server its not.

Can any expert guide me to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

By clicking on Project name in SonarQube Server can you verify if you can see this screen

[SonarImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9mh4.png)
In my case after clicking on master from this screen, I have different git branch and was able to see my result was published in that branch.